# Render view in higher script path with Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, zend-view

Lets assume the following code within a controller:

```
$this->view->addScriptPath('dir1/views/scripts');
$this->view->addScriptPath('dir2/views/scripts');
$this->render('index.phtml');
```

Where dir1/views/scripts contains 2 files:

```
-index.phtml  
-table.phtml
```

And dir2/views/scripts:

```
-table.phtml
```

Now, it will render the index.phtml in dir1 since dir 2 doesn't have an index.phtml.

Index.phtml looks something like:

```
<somehtml>
       <?= $this->render('table.phtml') ?>
</somehtml>
```

This is where the confusion starts for me. I would expect it to render the table.phtml in the last directory added to the script path stack, but it doesn't.
Is there a simple solution/explanation to my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up extending Zend_View and adding the function renderParent:

```
class My_View extends Zend_View
{
    private $_file = null;

    private $_name = null;

    /**
     * Finds a view script from the available directories.
     *
     * @param $name string The base name of the script.
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _script($name)
    {
        $this->_file = parent::_script($name);
        $this->_name = $name;

        return $this->_file;
    }

    /**
     * Renders the parent script by looping through all the script paths.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function renderParent()
    {
        $scriptPaths = $this->getScriptPaths();

        $found = false;
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($scriptPaths); $i++) {
            if ($this->_file == $scriptPaths[$i] . $this->_name) {
                $found = true;
            } elseif ($found) {
                if (is_readable($scriptPaths[$i] . $this->_name)) {
                    return $this->_run($scriptPaths[$i] . $this->_name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems that paths are used in LIFO order.

Take a look at `viewRednderer` and `view` source files to see how does it work.

Answer (score 0):

u can use

```
> $this->view->setBasePath("../application/dir1/views");
```

that is more specific